# How to download javascript image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to include gallery like this to my website, but i don't know how to download it. Is any way to do this? Here is the gallery

http://www.ultimateluxurychalets.com/luxury-chalet-white-pearl-val-disere

Comment: You will either need to find the person or company that built the gallery or find something similar. Taking content or code without permission is copyright violation

Comment: You should become familiar with the chrome or firefox dev tools. Read this how to figure it out. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one they're using:
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

They've skinned the left and right buttons.